Interesting Olympiad Locus Problem with coordinate bashing
Given circles $\omega_1$ and  $\omega_2$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of line-segment joining both circles centers. Point $X$ and $Y$ on $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ respectively such that $MX$=$MY$.
Find locus of midpoint of $X$ and $Y$.
I have a solution with coordinate geometry, please check my solution and please share if you have any thought or any alternative solution or idea regarding the problem...

My Solution  ...
Let 2 circles $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be on $x$ axis on coordinate $(-d/2,0)$ and $(+d/2,0)$.
$\omega_1: (x+\frac{d}{2})^2+y^2=r_1^2$
$\omega_2: (x-\frac{d}{2})^2+y^2=r_2^2$
And let $MX=MY=l$
So, coordinate of point $X$ is solution of equation from $MX=l$ and $\omega_1$
\begin{equation}
    \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{3} 
        &(x+\frac{d}{2})^2+y^2=r_1^2
 & \quad  \\
        &x^2+y^2=l^2
    \end{alignedat}
    \right.
\end{equation}
Which is :
$X: (\frac{l^2}{d}+\frac{d}{4}-\frac{r_2^2}{d},±\sqrt{l^2-\frac{l^4}{d^2}-\frac{d^2}{16}-\frac{r_2^4}{d^2}-\frac{l^2}{2}+\frac{r_2^2}{2}+\frac{
2r_2^2l^2}{d^2}})$
And similarly we get ,
$Y: (-\frac{l^2}{d}-\frac{d}{4}+\frac{r_1^2}{d},±\sqrt{l^2-\frac{l^4}{d^2}-\frac{d^2}{16}-\frac{r_1^4}{d^2}-\frac{l^2}{2}+\frac{r_1^2}{2}+\frac{
2r_2^2l^2}{d^2}})$
So the mid point of $X$,$Y$ will have $x$ coordinate =$\frac{r_2^2-r_1^2}{2d}=$constant
And variable $y$ coordinate.
So it will be a straight line....

Is this solution correct ?

Since you asked for other views, here's a partial solution along synthetic lines, which I expect could be developed into a full solution.
A quick specific solution: Presuming the circles to be outside one another as in your diagram, construct the bitangent lines. There will be 4 lines and 8 touchpoints, symmetric in pairs about the line $C_1C_2$ joining centers of the circle. I only marked $T_1,T_3$ here. Draw perpendicular bisector $TM$ with $M$ on $C_1C_2$. Then by symmetry about $TM$ and also about $C_1C_2$ we have all blue lines equal and thus concentric about $M$. But $C_1C_2T_3T_1$ is a trapezoid with midpoint $T$ so $M$ is a midpoint of $C_1C_2$. A similar argument shows the other four touchpoints also lie in a circle on $M$. So we have two sets of 4 points, all concentric about $M$. It is well-known that the radical axis of two circles is defined as the line on which any point has equal tangents to the two circles, and it is well-known that $T$ and the other midpoints of bitangents lie on the radical axis. So we have at least 4 midpoints lying on the radical axis (red), suggestive of the general solution.

You have developed the algebraic solution identifying the radical axis. Knowing this, I'll just point out a different synthetic road to a solution, again illustrating with circles outside one another: reflect the smaller circle about the perpendicular to $C_1C_2$ at $M$ to lie concentric with the larger circle (blue $\rightarrow$ blue dashed circles). Any circle on $M$ that cuts both circles (e.g., little dotted circle) will do so at locations such as $H', H_1,H_2$, and, if these points are joined, we see that $H_1H_2 \perp C_1C_2$ by symmetry, and that midpoints $M_1M_2$ likewise lie perpendicular to $C_1C_2$ and by symmetry about $M$ must lie at the same distance (height) from $C_1C_2$ as the midpoints $M_1',M_2'$ between the original circles, I used some faint parallels to indicate this. Likewise, by symmetry, the true midpoints lie beyond $M$ (laterally) at a distance of the projection, e.g., $M_1H_1$ on the line of centers $C_1C_2$. If we extend $H_1H_2$ to form a right triangle $H'VH_2$ then $H'V$ is twice that projection. But since you have shown the locus in question is the radical axis, the distance $RM$ is constant. Hence $H'V=2RM$ is constant, implying that the locus of $V$ is the larger circle translated a distance $2RM$ along the line of centers (the faint dashed circle). The gap in this proof from a synthetic point of view would be to prove the part in italics in reverse: prove that $H'V$ is constant and equal to $2RM$, then you know all midpoints lie on the radical axis.

